# How to add Ⓒ symbol in resource file to support in Japanese Windows OS.

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I need to  add copy right symbol Ⓒ in my resource file(.rc). When I add this symbol in '.rc' file and run the app on Japanese OS, it displays ? symbol instead.
Below is my code line.

```
LTEXT "Ⓒ 2017 Comapny Inc. All rights reserved.",IDC_COPYRIGHT,7,30,211,8
```

I tried editing this symbol on Japanese locale machine machine but still the issue was not resolved. Ⓒ symbol gets converted to ? symbol when I save the .rc file. 
On Japanese machine I see the above code as below:

```
LTEXT "? 2017 Comapny Inc. All rights reserved.",IDC_COPYRIGHT,7,30,211,8
```

Please share your idea how this can be done

Comment: Why aren't you using Unicode?

Comment: Life's too short to get you to explain what text encoding you told your text editor to use, whether or not the file has a BOM and how the string is rendered on the screen.  Use `(C) 2017` instead.

Comment: Or just say Copyright. If your application is localized, the translators will know what to do with it.  Not always so with iconic symbolsl. Also, legally since 2000 there is no reason to use "All rights reserved." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_rights_reserved

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a lot of work to save that file as Unicode (code page 1200). In Visual Studio that's the only sane way to deal with non-ascii characters anyway, or you'll be very surprised when you copy that file to a PC which is set up to use English.

Comment: @roeland: Explaining, which buttons to press is easy. Explaining *why* is the hard part. Hans Passant's comment was on the latter.

Comment: @IInspectable Agree, you don't need all the pesky details. If the file is saved as "Unicode" it means the same across machines. If it's saved as "ansi" you may read garbage on another PC. The end. It's easy enough to save as Unicode to just do it. And while you can write (c) instead of ©, most languages cannot be written in ASCII alone.

Answer (score 5):

The ANSI code page for the Japanese Windows locale is 932 (similar to Shift-JIS). This encoding does not include the copyright sign (U+00A9 `©`), nor the character you mention above (circled letter C, U+24D2 `ⓒ`, which is probably not what you wanted). If you are compiling resource files in code page 932, you will have to use plain ASCII `(c)`.

Alternatively if you can convert the RC file to an encoding that supports Unicode you can use any character you like. This could be UTF-16LE (the encoding that Notepad misleadingly describes as “Unicode”), or UTF-8 if you include `#pragma code_page(65001)` (but then you have to make sure to not edit in the resource editor which will mess that up).

Comment: For extra fun, you can have multiple `#pragma code_page()` in your resource file. Different sections will be decoded differently.