# MFC: how to display copyright symbol?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

Currently, I query copyright info and display it using DrawText. But it is less ideal that the copyright symbol is displayed as "(c)". Is there way to display it as a circle around c? I've searched around but not found yet any working code. For reference, below is what I use now.

```
VerQueryValue(ver_info, TEXT("\\StringFileInfo\\01234567\\LegalCopyright"), &lplpBuffer, &sz);
strncpy(buf, (char *)lplpBuffer, sz);
m_copyright = (CString)buf;
pDC->DrawText(m_copyright, rc, DT_LEFT | DT_SINGLELINE);
```

It will output "Copyright (c) ...", which I want to replace "(c)". The solution should work on Visual Studio 2008, if possible.

The following code only shows uA9, not copyright symbol.

```
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here
    CRect rect(50, 50, 200, 200);
    DrawTextW(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), L"\uA9", -1, rect, DT_LEFT | DT_SINGLELINE);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you simply use character U+A9? The Unicode character code for the copyright sign.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but DrawText(U+49,...) gives compilation error. BTW, when I set up the project, I didn't choose unicode support. Does it need to turn on?

Comment: At this point with windows development you should definitely prefer Unicode over multi-byte characters (I know the name is odd given that Unicode is itself a multi-byte encoding, MBCS originated to distinguish those character encodings from earlier single-byte encodings like ASCII but Unicode was was always treated as something else). Try the string L"\uA9" with the DrawTextW function (also notice that it is a capital 'A' not the digit '4').

Comment: As mentioned above, the copyright sign is character A9. And I would like to add that it is A9 in most ANSI codepages as well, so you should have no problem entering the character in your source (as a hex character literal) or in the resource file, even copying and pasting it from another source.

Comment: Is there any easier approach because all needed is just to draw one symbol? To use DrawTextW, I have to change quite a couple places of my project because initially when the project was created it didn't select unicode support.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, Could you check my new edit? Thanks.

Comment: Try this: Copy the character from here ©, paste it into notepad and save it as a text file with ANSI encoding. Then open the text file, copy the character from there (this is guaranteed to be in multi-byte format), and paste it into your code or a resource string, which can be displayed using the `DrawText()` (not `DrawTextW()`) function, or given to a control.

Comment: Not able to do it, when you try to save as ANSI it pops out warning regarding data loss.

Comment: Checked, and it works for me. Actually I pasted it directly into the source file, and as the source is in ANSI format, this converts it from unicode to multi-byte. And as said above, the same character code (A9) is used for almost all ANSI codepages. My system default codepage is 1252 (Western European) fyi. Anyways, you have already found a solution for your problem.

Comment: I copy © to rc file, the about box shows the symbol but with a preceding Â, how to get rid of that? Thank you.

Comment: nvm, saving rc with UTF-16LE solves the issue, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252059/how-to-add-symbol-in-resource-file-to-support-in-japanese-windows-os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could try to use this character “\xa9” to display copyright sign, which is like:

`DrawTextW(pDC->GetSafeHdc(), L"\xa9", -1, rect, DT_LEFT | DT_SINGLELINE);`

Note: please refer utf8 character table here: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex